# How to reslove Error 'database is locked' while publishing on Asp .net core 3.1 in azure appservice linux with healthchecks UI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

We are working on health checks in .NET Core 3.1.
We are using `AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.UI` for rendering Health checks UI. 
While publishing to Azure App service Linux machine we got the below error

> Microsoft.Data.SqlLite.SqlLiteexception (0x80004005): SQLLite Error 5:
>   'database is locked'

Comment: @iSahilSharma Good edit, but please do not format the name of products as code. ".NET Core 3.1" is not a piece of code and should not be formatted as such.